# Facebook Share button & Twitter tweet button interfering with my own javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter

I am working on a website , which hosts different JavaScript games. Player with high scores , get their names posted on the website.Here's [a link] (https://vast-escarpment-5866.herokuapp.com/). You can login with gmail account.

Problem is I want to add facebook share button and twitter buttons on this website. **The JavaScript code from my website , which deliver the high score to the server , is interfering with the JavaScript code of facebook button and twitter button.**[See the error messages or interference from the twitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60B6M.png) Although at the end both platform share the web-page.

This is the twitter code , I have in my html file.
`<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>`

This is my javascript code in another html `var message =  {
     messageType: "SETTING",
     options: {
       "width": 500, //Integer
       "height": 450 //Integer
       }
   };
   window.parent.postMessage(message, "*");`

Can any body please tell me , how to stop , this interference?

Comment: got twitter code from this website (https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet)

Comment: What “interference” are you talking about? I only see a message about some POST request that went wrong in your screenshot – but without any actual error message (apart from `KeyError`), and that sounds rather ike a server-side problem.

Comment: The problem is , even if i add the facebook button , there is another error plopped like the previous one , "String indices's must be integers" ..............So the problem is in server side code , should i look over there?